# preg_replace returns a literal \n instead of a newline

Tags: php, regex, escaping, newline

This

```
$stringToSearch = "sometext\nold\nmoretext";
$old_val = "old";
$new_val = "new";
$replaceString = preg_replace('/\A(.+\n)?'.$old_val.'(\n.+)?\Z/', '${1}. "$new_val" . '${2}', $stringToSearch);
```

does not seem to be retaining the original newline characters in $stringToSearch, but is returning them as literal '\n', like so:

```
var_dump($replaceString);
```

produces:

```
string(11) 
"sometext\nnew\nmoretext"
```

How can I get this to output the following:

```
string(11) 
"sometext
new
moretext"
```

Comment: Try using double-quotes `"` instead of single-quotes `'`.

Comment: I've tried converting all quotes to double quotes and vice-versa. I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: Around the replacement value.

Comment: Yeah, no go merlin, thanks though.

Comment: `$replceString = preg_replace('/\A(.+\n)?'.$old_val.'(\n.+)?\Z/', '${1}'. $new_val . '${2}', $stringToSearch);`

This should work.

Comment: I would use `preg_replace('/^(.*?)old(.*)$/s', '$1'. "$new_val" . '$2', $stringToSearch);`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$stringToSearch = "sometext\nold\nmoretext";
$old_val = "old";
$new_val = "new";
$replaceString = preg_replace('/\A(.+\n)?'.$old_val.'(\n.+)?\Z/', '${1}' . "$new_val" . '${2}', $stringToSearch);

var_dump ( $replaceString );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(21) "sometext
new
moretext"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following changes in quotes gives the output that you desire.

```
<?php
$stringToSearch = "sometext\nold\nmoretext";
$old_val = "old";
$new_val = "new";
$replaceString = preg_replace('/\A(.+\n)?'.$old_val.'(\n.+)?\Z/', 
    "$1". "$new_val" . "$2", $stringToSearch);

var_dump($replaceString);
?>
```

Comment: @Stephen, There are many right answers, and infinitely many wrong answers. :P